# Early Christmas Gift from Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I received around **100+** reputations in ***all*** of the Sites that I use under stack exchange today morning. So, SE distributing early Christmas gifts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an **[Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200)**, because you reached 200 reputation points on one of your accounts and yes, assume them as Christmas gift as well!!!